# Django selenium how to get page text using find_element

Tags: javascript, python, django, selenium, django-testing

I am trying to get the the text 'Incorrect Credentials' using selenium.

This is what I have tried...

```
message_text = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="toast-container"]/div/div[1][@class="ng-binding toast-title"]')
print(message_text.text)
```

also tried:

```
 message_text = self.driver. find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toast-container"]/div/div[1][@class="ng-binding toast-title"]').text
```

But I just get an empty string.

The text only gets added to the page via JS.

Any idea why it is blank?

This is the rendered html...

```
<div ng-repeat="toaster in toasters" class="toast ng-scope toast-error" ng-class="toaster.type"
     ng-click="click(toaster)" ng-mouseover="stopTimer(toaster)" ng-mouseout="restartTimer(toaster)" style="">
    <button class="toast-close-button" ng-show="config.closeButton">×</button>
    <div ng-class="config.title" class="ng-binding toast-title">Incorrect Credentials</div>
    <div ng-class="config.message" ng-switch="" on="toaster.bodyOutputType" class="toast-message">
        <!-- ngSwitchWhen: trustedHtml --><!-- ngSwitchWhen: template --><!-- ngSwitchDefault:  -->
        <div ng-switch-default="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Incorrect Email/Password</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

This works, but is really bad....

```
    self._login_process()


    import time
    time.sleep(10)

    element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "toast-title"))
    )
```

UPDATE

Got this to work with...

```
 element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "toast-title"), 'Incorrect Credentials')
        )
```

Comment: @Brandon yes and message_text.text should have the value 'Incorrect Credentials' but it is blank. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you using a LiveServerTestCase? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase You should be able to use the built-in `.find_element_by_id()` method instead of XPATH

Comment: I have tried self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('toast-title') with no joy. Maybe I need to wait?

Comment: You'll definitely need to give your ajax / dom manipulation time to complete. I personally find QUnit tests easier to deal with for this type of testing.

Comment: @Brandon solved it, can I make  selenium wait for a http status code?

Comment: If memory serves, checking for the status code is problematic and might only work in Firefox

Comment: @Brandon thank for your help, made me think! resolved it with text_to_be_present_in_element :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working. You should answer your own question so it will help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I needed to wait for the AJAX call to complete first before check for the value.

2) The message box was already rendered with a blank value on creation of the page.

To resolve this I needed to wait until the text in the message box changed...

```
 element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CLASS_NAME, "toast-title"), 'Incorrect Credentials')
        )
```

element now returns `True` if the text `Incorrect Credentials` is not found within x seconds. I can check for this using...

```
 noz.assert_equal(element, True)
```